# Python Selenium send_keys one by one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

```
https://www.bccard.com/app/merchant/Login.do
```

I am trying to login to this site automatically using Python-Selenium. However, as you might noticed the password input place is not receiving `driver.send_keys`.

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.bccard.com/app/merchant/Login.do')
time.sleep(2)
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.dismiss()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userid"]').send_keys('id')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwd"]').send_keys('pw')
```

Comment: What exactly problem are you facing with your current code?

Comment: When you run this code , it cannot input the value to the website password form

Comment: I think the website banned ctrl-v

Comment: I meant what error are you receiving?

Comment: @Robinshim ctrl+v may be really banned. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 The site starts blocking automated requests after some amount of them is sent. I've added one option on how to avoid bot detection. Look for similar questions on this.

2 You can wait for you alert and check the text inside it.

3 Do not Use time.sleep, use implicit/explicit wait
Points 2 and 3 were the main problems in your code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
#  Try adding user agent to avoid bot detection
# options.add_argument('user-agent=')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.bccard.com/app/merchant/Login.do')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
assert "INISAFE CrossWebEX" in alert.text
alert.dismiss()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li>#userid').send_keys('id')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span>#passwd').send_keys('pw')
time.sleep(7)  # just to make sure that the values was entered.
```

**UPDATE and solution**

I found out that you start seing a virtual keyboard after some amount of attempts. So, you can bypass it with Javascript:

```
field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span>#passwd')
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value='pw'", field)
```

Instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span>#passwd').send_keys('pw')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me, just switch:

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
```

To this:

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
```

`switch_to_alert()` is deprecated and errors out in Pycharm, at least for me.

Other than that UserID and Password filled out fine

Comment: well, my question was how can I send key on password input

Comment: the website's password input does not work with selenium key_send

Comment: How can I solve my problem than. 
Is there any other ways to send id and password to the site?

Comment: I have no idea as I can't replicate your issue.  `send_keys('pw')` works fine for me and sends 2 asterisks `**` to the password field.   Good luck, hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can introduce explicit wait for more stability. The below code works for me :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\cruisepandey\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.bccard.com/app/merchant/Login.do")
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.dismiss()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'userid'))).send_keys('Robin shim')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'passwd'))).send_keys('Robin shim password')
print("login successfully")
```

[image: Check out the output]